# Swing display JPanels in a row to the right corner

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, gridbaglayout

I am creating a custom decoration for my first customized Swing program window, I just started with layout managers, and it looks like I am doing something wrong, first I used BorderLayout and BorderLayout.EAST or WEST to display on the corner, but it only allows one panel to be displayed on a corner, like it won't display in a row.

Looks like this:

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/448ffc85c1568fd281ee6b2a4079a482.png))</sub>

With that code:

```
    this.panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


    this.panel.add(this.createToolButton("X"), BorderLayout.EAST);
```

But if I add another panel, the newest panel will be **on** the previous one *(Note I used panels because JButton hates me, with it's default styles doesn't let me make it flat)*

Now I used GridBagLayout

```
    this.panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    Box panels = new Box(BoxLayout.X_AXIS);

    panels.add(this.createToolButton("X"));

    this.panel.add(panels, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

But on run I get

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot add to layout: constraints must be a GridBagConstraint
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.addLayoutComponent(Unknown Source)
```

What am I doing wrong? how can I have the panels floated to right one by one?

EDIT:

```
    this.panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

    gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    this.panel.add(this.createToolButton("X"), gc);
```

Comment: this.panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); and  this.panel.add(panels, BorderLayout.EAST); don't really fit together. you would have to set the Layout to new BorderLayout()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" *java.lang.IllegalArgumentException*: cannot add to layout: constraints must be a GridBagConstraint
>       at java.awt.GridBagLayout.addLayoutComponent(Unknown Source)

Use `GridBagConstraint` with `GridBagLayout`.

```
this.panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraint gc = new GridBagConstraint();
// set different properties of GridBagConstraint as per your need
this.panel.add(panels, gc);
```

Read more [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) read more about properties of [GridBagConstraint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html).

Here is [The Example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/GridBagLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/GridBagLayoutDemo.java) to learn more about it.

---

#### EDIT

You can try with `FlowLayout` with right alignment:

```
JPanel titlePanel=new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
titlePanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
titlePanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT, 0, 0));
panel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

titlePanel.add(new JLabel("Title",JLabel.LEFT));
panel.add(new JButton("X"));
titlePanel.add(panel);

frame.add(titlePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
// add panel in the north section of the undecorated JFrame 
// that by default uses BorderLayout
```

snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! this works, however is there a way to remove this padding http://gyazo.com/88058d4ae0ec69f8ebf1b902595f6f02 ?

Comment: @BenBeri: Take a `JPanel` set it's layout to [__GridLayout(1, 0)__](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html), add  the `JButton`s to this `JPanel` and now add this `JPanel` to the `JPanel` with `FlowLayout`, that will do :-)

Comment: use `new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT,0,0)`

Comment: You're just awesome, worked fine! thanks a lot mate.

Comment: @Braj **question**: Will it be a problem to implement a text on the left side of that panel in the future?

Comment: @BenBeri That can be addressed easily and there are lots of ways to do it. If you think so then I'll update my post with left aligned text as well. Give me some time, please.

Comment: Al right thanks for your time Braj, I tried adding a Label with FlowLayout.LEFT, but it just goes after the buttons like this: http://gyazo.com/718723345409fafc1dbb8a6e3abbb3cc

Comment: use GridLayout and then add JLabel and JPanel.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using

```
this.panel.add(panels, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

then you should use `BorderLayout` not `GridBagLayout`.

```
this.panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

You can read more in the documentation [How to Use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html).

Comment: That code corresponded to what OP had written. Honestly I have used Swing a lot with java 6 and i always use `BorderLayout.EAST`. So yes I took for granted it would be the same in the doc. Surprisingly never encountered this before. Tx for pointing that out :)

Comment: Awww, that's OKAY, we all tend to miss many a thingies. Sometimes, somethingies are meant for others to be shown to oneself. It had happened with me too :-) (though keep that on the low)